# How to delete everything (roles, tables, functions, types, ... ) in a database cluster without re-installing PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, restore

I have made a mistake while restoring a PostgreSQL database cluster of 4 databases. Now, I want to restore my backup again with the correct file, but there are many roles, types and functions from the old erroneous restore. I deleted every database except postgres default DB. However, roles are still there and functions and types are also there.

How can I clear everything in a PostgreSQL cluster and have a fresh start without having to uninstall and install PostgreSQL on this machine.

I read on the internet that I should delete everything in /data directory of PostgreSQL!! I am afraid it may damage something.

Any better way to do it?

When I do \l in psql tool I have the following result:

[image]

Comment: The `role`'s are global and are not really an issue, you will just get a message that the `role` already exists. The `postgres` database is not actually  the default database it's primary purpose is to serve as a database to connect to to use to bootstrap work on other databases. When you connect to `postgres` using `psql` and do `\l` what is returned? Add that information to question. **You do not have to delete the data directory**.

Comment: So is it ok to create another DB and then drop postgres DB? Then, I will have to drop roles one by one

Comment: Connect to  the `postgres` database using `psql`  and see if there are objects in it. In other words do `\df` and `\dt` to see if there are functions and tables respectively.  If there are then probably the easiest thing would be to drop the `postgres` database. You will need to connect to the `template1` database to do that.  While I was in `template1` I would make sure that objects have not been created there also. Then I would recreate the `postgres` database using `CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH template template0` as many tools expect `postgres` to be there.

Comment: In `psql` you can use `\du` to see the roles global to the cluster. How did you take the dump of the other database cluster e.g. what was the full `pg_dump` command you used?

Comment: Yes, I took a backup from the cluster and that is why the roles are transferred to the new postgreSQL instance.
I think except roles, everything else will be deleted by deleting postgres DB. 
Am I right?

Comment: Have you determined whether the objects are in the `postgres` database? You referred to restoring a cluster of 4 databases but only show 3, what happened to the fourth?